# How to Run Java Code from Gradle at Build Time

Tags: java, gradle, jsonschema2pojo

I'm using [jsonschema-generator](https://github.com/victools/jsonschema-generator) to generate a JSON schema file based on my POJOs. Currently I'm doing it via a test that is run during the `gradle build` step. This works fine but it doesn't feel right as really what I'm doing is not testing anything.

I've also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21358586/1195527) which details how to run it on `gradle run` but this is not ideal either as it will pointlessly execute this every time the application comes up but not when I build.

**Therefore, is there a way to tell gradle (in `build.gradle`) to run a piece of Java code at build time?**

For completeness, here the code I'm looking to run:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.github.victools.jsonschema.generator.Option;
import com.github.victools.jsonschema.generator.OptionPreset;
import com.github.victools.jsonschema.generator.SchemaGenerator;
import com.github.victools.jsonschema.generator.SchemaGeneratorConfig;
import com.github.victools.jsonschema.generator.SchemaGeneratorConfigBuilder;
import com.mypackage.MyClass;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Map;

@SuppressWarnings({"FieldCanBeLocal", "rawtypes"})
public class JsonSchemaGenerator {
    private final String SCHEMA_FOLDER = "schemas/";
    private final Map<Class, String> schemaToGenerate = Map.of(
            MyClass.class, "my-class.schema"
    );

    @Test
    public void generateJsonSchema() throws Exception {
        SchemaGeneratorConfigBuilder configBuilder = new SchemaGeneratorConfigBuilder(new ObjectMapper(), OptionPreset.PLAIN_JSON);
        SchemaGeneratorConfig config = configBuilder.with(Option.DEFINITIONS_FOR_ALL_OBJECTS).build();
        SchemaGenerator generator = new SchemaGenerator(config);

        for (var entry : schemaToGenerate.entrySet()) {
            JsonNode jsonSchema = generator.generateSchema(entry.getKey());
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(SCHEMA_FOLDER + entry.getValue());
            out.println(jsonSchema.toPrettyString());
            out.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could create a script that does gradle build then gradle run, and use that instead of just gradle build.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Christine. I don't think I can do that as it would bring up my application during the build on the CI box which would result in the build failing with a timeout so that wouldn't work in my case.

Comment: Then you need to edit the build file to make it happen the way you want it.

Comment: Hi @VladSchnakovszki, a Maven plugin is currently being worked on (https://github.com/victools/jsonschema-generator/issues/53). Once that is done, you might be able to trigger it from within your grade build somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [JavaExec Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html) seems to meet your requirements.

This allows you to run a `main()` method and thereby any Java Code you want – including whatever JSON Schema generation you like.

This [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36092290) also describes pretty much what you want to do.

---

Adapted from the linked documentation:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

task generateJsonSchema(type: JavaExec) {
  classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath

  main = 'package.Main'

  // arguments to pass to the application
  args 'appArg1'
}
```

As per `Jorn`'s comment below:

> You can depend the build task on your custom task: `build.dependsOn generateJsonSchema` if your custom task is defined as `task generateJsonSchema(type: JavaExec) { ... }`

Comment: `Exec` or `JavaExec` are generally correct, but this is not a good example... and no other task depends on it.

Comment: You’re saying this can also not be included in the `grade build` then?

Comment: You can depend the build task on your custom task: `build.dependsOn generateJsonSchema` if your custom task is defined as `task generateJsonSchema(type: JavaExec) { ... }`

Comment: @Carsten All I said/wrote that the initial version of the answer had no dependency defined with `dependsOn` or `finalizedBy`, as the question was asking for. An `Exec` task, wich runs a JAR with `java` from the command line might even be more suitable, because the code in there might not change much, therefore build it once would suffice.